# 500 Internal Server Error - GCP App Engine

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform

I am playing around in GCP App Engine and trying to use python to connect to a MySQL database, then return/print the first row of a specific table so that when the app link is click it displays something like this in the browser:

---

sub_event_id =  1234567

event_type   =  1

date_time    =  2019-09-22 00:00:00

ip           =  unknown

property_id  =  1

contact_id   =  1234567

address_id   =  1234567

---

Below is the code I am using and the error I am getting after I deploy the app.
Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

**Here is the code in my main.py file:**

```
from flask import Flask
import sqlalchemy as sa
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def dbresponse():
  engine = sa.create_engine('''mysql+pymysql://{username}:
                             {password}@{host}:{port}/{db_name}''')
      with engine.connect() as conn:
          # Execute the query and fetch all results
          response = conn.execute(
              "SELECT * FROM sub_events "
              "LIMIT 1"
          ).fetchall()
          # Print results
          for row in response:
              print("sub_event_id = ", row[0], )
              print("event_type   = ", row[1])
              print("date_time    = ", row[2])
              print("ip           = ", row[3])
              print("property_id  = ", row[4])
              print("contact_id   = ", row[5])
              print("address_id   = ", row[6], "\n")
      engine.dispose()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

**Here is the code in my app.yaml file:**

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

**Here is the code in my requirements.txt file:**

```
Flask==1.1.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.8
PyMySQL==0.9.3
```

**After Running `gcloud app deploy` and `gcloud app browse` then clicking the link that gets generated...**

**I get a 500 Internal Server Error:**

*500 Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.*

Comment: This error usually means your program crashed. Look in the Stackdriver log files for error messages. Most likely the database connection threw an exception, your code is not catching exceptions and App Engine terminated your program. Start with adding try/except blocks to catch errors.

Comment: Alternatively, you can run [`gcloud app logs tail`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/logs/tail) which is useful if your error log lies somewhere within `stderr,stdout,crash.log,nginx.request,request_log` which most of the time, is.

Comment: Are you following the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/cloud-sql/using-cloud-sql-mysql?hl) to establish the connection? I would do a test app to verify the connection, then try to add the logic of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Having an integer index in this for loop imposes a high risk of IndexError.

I would first check if rows have this size before printing.

There are two ways to do that (using try or checking len):

```
      for row in response:
          try:
              print("sub_event_id = ", row[0], )
              print("event_type   = ", row[1])
              print("date_time    = ", row[2])
              print("ip           = ", row[3])
              print("property_id  = ", row[4])
              print("contact_id   = ", row[5])
              print("address_id   = ", row[6], "\n")
          except IndexError:
              print("There is not complete data to print.")
```

or

```
        for row in response:
            if len(row) >= 7: 
                print("sub_event_id = ", row[0], )
                print("event_type   = ", row[1])
                print("date_time    = ", row[2])
                print("ip           = ", row[3])
                print("property_id  = ", row[4])
                print("contact_id   = ", row[5])
                print("address_id   = ", row[6], "\n")
            else:
                print("There is not complete data to print.")
```

It is also recommended configuring logs as @jkleinne pointed out.